# Link to a specific part of a web page doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I created a website with en explore button
code of the button:

```
  <a href="#sec" id="exploreBtn">Explore</a>
```

I liked it to this article

```
<article class="sec">
```

but when I press the button knowing happens

Comment: Anchor links use the `name` attribute or the `id` attribute, not classes. Multiple elements can have the same class, so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to give id to an anchor like for example 
`<a href="#sec" id="exploreBtn">Explore</a>` on pressing this you will go to `sec` id, which should be declared like this: `<article id='sec'>...</a>`

Answer (score 1):

The article should have id sec like the below piece of code, but you have written class sec.

`<article id="sec">`

Answer (score 1):

As you have called `id` `sec` in `a` tag not the `class` so you must have `sec` as `id` of your `article` tag
Change code to this :

```
<a href="#sec" id="exploreBtn">Explore</a>
<article id="sec">
```